# How to maximize value from a list when there is a price constraint

Tags: arrays, algorithm, set

I have 5 lists:

list 1: ['a', 21, $17], ['b', 19, $14], ['c', 17, $13], ['d', 16, $13]

list 2: ['e', 19, $14], ['f', 16, $12], ['g', 14, $12], ['h', 11, $06]

list 3: ['i', 13, $09], ['j', 11, $07], ['k', 10, $06], ['l', 07, $06]

list 4: ['m', 16, $06], ['n', 13, $05], ['o', 10, $05], ['p', 06, $05]

list 5: ['q', 21, $13], ['r', 19, $14], ['s', 17, $12], ['t', 15, $11]

My task is to pick 1 array from each list for a total of 5 arrays. I need to pick the set of arrays with the highest value (sum of all :value) where the price is $50 or under (sum of all :price).

How do I approach this problem without having to iterate through every element?

I know I can reduce the list to:

list 1: ['a', 21, $17], ['b', 19, $14], ['c', 17, $13]

list 2: ['e', 19, $14], ['f', 16, $12], ['h', 11, $06]

list 3: ['i', 13, $09], ['j', 11, $07], ['k', 10, $06]

list 4: ['m', 16, $06], ['n', 13, $05]

list 5: ['q', 21, $13], ['s', 17, $12], ['t', 15, $11]

where the array with a lower value but higher or equal price is eliminated when compared to its left neighbor.

However this is still too slow.

Comment: thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

This is well-known [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_programming_in_advance_algorithm).

In your case (as you have small integer price) it can be solved using dynamic programming. The simpler approach takes O(nW) time, where `n` is total number of elements in your sets and `W` is the weight limit (50 in your case).